# Flink Auto generated UIDs have been disabled but no UID or hash has been assigned to operator Partition

Tags: apache-flink

Using the latest flink version 1.9.1, and have set:

```
env.getConfig().disableAutoGeneratedUIDs();
```

I've provided uid's for all operators that I use (filter, flatmap, connect), but I get the following exception when I run:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Auto
>   generated UIDs have been disabled but no UID or hash has been assigned
>   to operator Partition

Operator Partition refers to the keyBy operator which I use, but there is no 'uid' function that I can apply to it:

[image: snapshot of flink uid missing]

What is the problem? What am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

This is a bug -- see [FLINK-14910](https://jira.apache.org/jira/browse/FLINK-14910). This will be fixed in 1.9.2 and 1.10.0.

As a workaround you could do

```
keyedStream = foo.keyBy(...)
keyedStream.getTransformation().setUid("blah")
```

See http://apache-flink-user-mailing-list-archive.2336050.n4.nabble.com/How-to-assign-a-UID-to-a-KeyedStream-td32052.html for a bit more discussion of this.